# How to match input with data in Python csv

Tags: python, csv, matching

The following program is for matching an integer with its Landcode

1. convert an ipadress to an integer
2. read a CSV file with contains mimimum and maximum integers given to a country
   The CSV contains minimum integer, maximum integer, tld and country
3. find out if the integer is inbetween which minimum and maximum
4. match the integer with its landcode : output should be like
   "3739147998  US"

I'm having trouble with matching these.
My output now gives the right integer but just gives a huge list of my integer + al the landcodes from the csv instead of the 1 matching it.
"""

```
import ipaddress

ipadressen = int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(input("Set an IP-adress")))
file = open("tld.csv", "r")

for line in file:
    fields = line.split(",")

# and let's extract the data:

minimum = fields[0]
maximum = fields[1]
landcode = fields[2]
country = fields[3]


if minimum <= str(ipadressen) <= maximum:
    print(str(ipadressen) + " ", landcode) """"
```

Comment: You can use `minimum, maximum, landcode, country = fields` if `fields` only has four elements. Or even `minimum, maximum, landcode, country, *_ = fields` if `fields` has more elements.

Comment: In `if minimum <= str(ipadressen) <= maximum:` you are comparing strings, not numbers. Since you convert the input IP address to a number for comparison, you should convert the IP address from the CSV file to numbers as well.